# setxbmap in ~/.xinitrc doesn't work

Tags: debian, dwm

Here's my `~/.xinitrc`:

```
 setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp &
setxkbmap  -layout us,ru -option grp:ctrl_shift_toggle
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --above LVDS-1
xset r rate 150 50
feh --bg-center ~/wallpaper.jpg  &
xwinwrap -b -fs -sp -fs -nf -ov  -- /usr/lib/xscreensaver/glmatrix -root -window-id WID &
xcompmgr &
xscreensaver -no-splash &
conky &
exec dwm
```

I can't use shift+ctrl somehow after starting dwm, but if I execute that command manually it starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent multiple months to find out why my mappings got overridden by something after the session starts. For me it was `ibus`. After removing it, my settings worked again.

```
apt remove ibus
apt autoremove
```

Use `apt autoremove` to be sure that everything gets cleaned up. It's a horrible idea to "magically" overwrite user settings after the session starts.